# css() not working with variable parameter in interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I want to move the canvas towards the right of the screen every 100ms interval. However it doesn't turn out to be moving at all. Why is this happening and what is the solution?

I also saw that instead of `hPos` if I put a value like `10` in its place, it's moving.

```js
var vx = 10;
canvas.css("top", "100px").css("left", "0");
var id = setInterval(frame, 100);

function frame() {
  var hPos = canvas.css("left");
  if (vx > 0) {
    hPos += vx;
    canvas.css("left", hPos + "px");
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see how to create a [MRE] and [edit] your question to include the HTML that this apples to, so that we can see the problem and be able to help.

Comment: I bet the value of `var hPos = canvas.css("left");` is a string. If `hPos` is `"10px"`, then `hPos+= vx` would result in `"10px10"`...not in `20`.

Comment: @FluffyKitten that's it?

Comment: Do some basic debugging! What is value of `hPos` before the css() call for example

Comment: @David784 Thanks. Understood

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because getting the `left` value using `css()` returns a string, eg. `10px`. You then append a `0` to that string making it `10px0`, which is clearly not a valid value.

To fix this, use `parseInt()` to create a valid integer value and then add to it within the interval. Try this:

```js
let canvas = $('#canvas');

var vx = 10;
canvas.css("top", "100px").css("left", "0");
var id = setInterval(frame, 100);

function frame() {
  var hPos = parseInt(canvas.css("left"), 10) || 0;
  if (vx > 0) {
    hPos += vx;
    canvas.css("left", hPos + "px");
  }
};
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #C00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```